# Retrieving email server software name

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

I wrote an Outlook (2010+) C# add-in and having some trouble with different email servers.
As I found specific solutions for each server type I would like to know if there is an way to get the information to which email server an Outlook account points? It would be totally sufficient to get the name of the underlying email server software as version numbers are not neccessary to know.

Something like

```
string serverSoftware = account.server.softwareName;
```

would be great...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look for the accounts clsid or service name in the registry.

For Outlook 2010 and earlier:

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows Messaging Subsystem\Profiles\{0}\9375CFF0413111d3B88A00104B2A6676
```

For Outlook 2013:

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\Profiles\{0}\9375CFF0413111d3B88A00104B2A6676
```

You have to replace {0} by Account.Session.CurrentProfileName

In this location iterate all subkeys and look for the "Account Name", that will match to Account.DisplayName

Okay, now it's getting a bit more difficult:

First check the value of "clsid" against this list:

- {ED475411-B0D6-11D2-8C3B-00104B2A6676} = Pop3
- {ED475412-B0D6-11D2-8C3B-00104B2A6676} = IMAP
- {ED475415-B0D6-11D2-8C3B-00104B2A6676} = Active Sync (Outlook 2013)
- {ED475414-B0D6-11D2-8C3B-00104B2A6676} = Exchange and other MAPI-like third-party

In case of the last clsid, check "Service Name". For Exchange accounts, it will be "MSEMS", while i.e. a Kerio Connect account would return "KERIOOCF" as service name.

Answer (score 0):

No, that information is not exposed at all - all Outlook knows is that it needs to access a particular remote server using POP3, SMTP or IMAP4.

What problem exactly are you trying to solve? Why exactly do you need to that?

Comment: I have some problems with a specific server software when copying an email. The server respons that this operation is not supported, so I have to create a new mailitem and copy the content and attachments manually. This workaround is ok, but I wanted to do it only when neccessary.
Is it possible to retrieve the information about server software somehow from outside of Outlook? (Windows API or something?)

Comment: What is the line of your code that raises the error? What is the exact error message? Is this about moving messages in an IMAP4 store?

Comment: I'll check this on monday and write you back.